# Prestashop Ngnix sitemap error

Tags: nginx, config, configuration, sitemap, prestashop

*Сервер построен на ngnix. Файлы sitemap в корне сайта есть, но при попытки зайти по адресу в браузере для просмотра карты, например http://site.com/1_index_sitemap.xml белая страница с "File not found."*

Error log:

> [error] 2215#0: *55416 FastCGI sent in stderr: "Primary script unknown" while reading response header from upstream, client: 195.191.159.197, server: site.com, request: "GET /1_index_sitemap.xml HTTP/1.1", upstream: "fastcgi://127.0.0.1:9000", host: "site.com", referrer: "http://site.com/wefwefwef343354534/index.php?controller=AdminModules&token=564455667498a58c1b614f2315f24a&configure=gsitemap&tab_module=seo&module_name=gsitemap"

Ngnix config:

```
  server {
    listen      93.170.121.210:80;
    server_name site.com www.site.com;

    root        /home/admin/web/site.com/public_html;
    index index.html index.htm index.php;

    location ~ \.php$ {
      fastcgi_pass   127.0.0.1:9000;
      fastcgi_index  index.php;
      fastcgi_param  SCRIPT_FILENAME  $document_root$fastcgi_script_name;
      fastcgi_buffer_size 256k;
      fastcgi_buffers 8 256k;
      include        fastcgi_params;
    }
  }
```

Comment: Не задавайте вопросов состоящих только из копипаста ошибок, добавьте своих пояснений.

Comment: *зайти по адресу* — по какому?

Comment: Это у Вас весь конфиг? И ЧПУ работает? Версия "престы" какая?

Comment: версия престы 1.6.1.5 Нет это не весь файл конфигурации только часть об fastcgi. как я понял в нем заковырка

Comment: адрес для просмотра карты сайта , например http://site.com/1_index_sitemap.xml

Comment: Зачем вы выложили эту часть конфига? У вас же проблема *не в fastcgi*, а в том что *fastcgi срабатывает когда не просят*! Показывайте остальной конфиг, особенно ту часть, которая отвечает за редирект. Или попробуйте сами найти там ошибку, зная что она именно в редиректе.

Answer (score 1):

на сервере был еще один конфиг **nginx.site.com.conf** который частично дублировал основной. после очистки содержания все заработало. спасибо всем за внимание к моей проблеме